# Working with arrays and reading text files

Tags: c

Hey, I've been working on this problem to read numbers from a text file and store them in an array but for some reason can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. the assignment is to implement the markov chain algorithm. I've made the reading part and assigning the array in the main fun() but i keep getting undeclared identifier as an error. Here is the code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "eprintf.h"

enum {
    NPREF   = 2,    /* number of prefix words */
    NHASH   = 4093, /* size of state hash table array */
    MAXGEN  = 10000 /* maximum words generated */
};

typedef struct State State;
typedef struct Suffix Suffix;

struct State {  /* prefix + suffix list */
    char    *pref[NPREF];   /* prefix words */
    Suffix  *suf;           /* list of suffixes */
    State   *next;          /* next in hash table */
};

struct Suffix { /* list of suffixes */
    char    *word;          /* suffix */
    Suffix  *next;          /* next in list of suffixes */
};

State   *lookup(char *prefix[], int create);
void    build(char *prefix[], FILE*);
void    generate(int nwords);
void    add(char *prefix[], char *word);

State   *statetab[NHASH];   /* hash table of states */

char NONWORD[] = "\n";  /* cannot appear as real word */

//FILE* random_reader;
//FILE* myfile;


/* markov main: markov-chain random text generation */
int main(void)
{
    int i, nwords = MAXGEN;
    char *prefix[NPREF];        /* current input prefix */

    FILE* random_reader;
    FILE* myfile;

    int c;
    //long seed;

    setprogname("markov");
    //seed = time(NULL);

    //srand(seed);
    random_reader = fopen("../random_num.txt","r");
    myfile = fopen("../alice30.txt","r");
    int element;
    int random_num[10000];
    char line; //each number
    int i=0;
    while(fgets(line, 20, random_reader)!=NULL)  // update the array
    {
        sscanf(line,"%o",&element);
        random_num[i]=element;
        i++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NPREF; i++) /* set up initial prefix */
        prefix[i] = NONWORD;
    build(prefix, stdin);
    add(prefix, NONWORD);
    generate(nwords);
    return 0;
}   

const int MULTIPLIER = 31;  /* for hash() */

/* hash: compute hash value for array of NPREF strings */
unsigned int hash(char *s[NPREF])
{
    unsigned int h;
    unsigned char *p;
    int i;

    h = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < NPREF; i++)
        for (p = (unsigned char *) s[i]; *p != '\0'; p++)
            h = MULTIPLIER * h + *p;
    return h % NHASH;
}

/* lookup: search for prefix; create if requested. */
/*  returns pointer if present or created; NULL if not. */
/*  creation doesn't strdup so strings mustn't change later. */
State* lookup(char *prefix[NPREF], int create)
{
    int i, h;
    State *sp;

    h = hash(prefix);
    for (sp = statetab[h]; sp != NULL; sp = sp->next) {
        for (i = 0; i < NPREF; i++)
            if (strcmp(prefix[i], sp->pref[i]) != 0)
                break;
        if (i == NPREF)     /* found it */
            return sp;
    }
    if (create) {
        sp = (State *) emalloc(sizeof(State));
        for (i = 0; i < NPREF; i++)
            sp->pref[i] = prefix[i];
        sp->suf = NULL;
        sp->next = statetab[h];
        statetab[h] = sp;
    }
    return sp;
}

/* addsuffix: add to state. suffix must not change later */
void addsuffix(State *sp, char *suffix)
{
    Suffix *suf;

    suf = (Suffix *) emalloc(sizeof(Suffix));
    suf->word = suffix;
    suf->next = sp->suf;
    sp->suf = suf;
}

/* add: add word to suffix list, update prefix */
void add(char *prefix[NPREF], char *suffix)
{
    State *sp;

    sp = lookup(prefix, 1);  /* create if not found */
    addsuffix(sp, suffix);
    /* move the words down the prefix */
    memmove(prefix, prefix+1, (NPREF-1)*sizeof(prefix[0]));
    prefix[NPREF-1] = suffix;
}

/* build: read input, build prefix table */
void build(char *prefix[NPREF], FILE *f)
{
    char buf[100], fmt[10];

    /* create a format string; %s could overflow buf */
    sprintf(fmt, "%%%ds", sizeof(buf)-1);
    while (fscanf(f, fmt, buf) != EOF)
        add(prefix, estrdup(buf));
}

/* generate: produce output, one word per line */
void generate(int nwords)
{
    State *sp;
    Suffix *suf;
    char *prefix[NPREF], *w;
    int i, nmatch;

    for (i = 0; i < NPREF; i++) /* reset initial prefix */
        prefix[i] = NONWORD;

    for (i = 0; i < nwords; i++) {
        sp = lookup(prefix, 0);
        if (sp == NULL)
            eprintf("internal error: lookup failed");
        nmatch = 0;
        for (suf = sp->suf; suf != NULL; suf = suf->next)
            if (rand() % ++nmatch == 0) /* prob = 1/nmatch */
                w = suf->word;
        if (nmatch == 0)
            eprintf("internal error: no suffix %d %s", i, prefix[0]);
        if (strcmp(w, NONWORD) == 0)
            break;
        printf("%s\n", w);
        memmove(prefix, prefix+1, (NPREF-1)*sizeof(prefix[0]));
        prefix[NPREF-1] = w;
    }
}

******* Here are the eprintf header file**************

/* eprintf.h: error wrapper functions */
extern  void    eprintf(char *, ...);
extern  void    weprintf(char *, ...);
extern  char    *estrdup(char *);
extern  void    *emalloc(size_t);
extern  void    *erealloc(void *, size_t);
extern  char    *progname(void);
extern  void    setprogname(char *);

#define NELEMS(a)   (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))


*******here is the eprintf source file*********
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "eprintf.h"
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

static char *name = NULL;  /* program name for messages */

/* eprintf: print error message and exit */
void eprintf(char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;

    fflush(stdout);
    if (progname() != NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", progname());

    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    if (fmt[0] != '\0' && fmt[strlen(fmt)-1] == ':')
        fprintf(stderr, " %s", strerror(errno));
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    exit(2); /* conventional value for failed execution */
}

/* weprintf: print warning message */
void weprintf(char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;

    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(stderr, "warning: ");
    if (progname() != NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", progname());
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (fmt[0] != '\0' && fmt[strlen(fmt)-1] == ':')
        fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", strerror(errno));
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}

/* emalloc: malloc and report if error */
void *emalloc(size_t n)
{
    void *p;

    p = malloc(n);
    if (p == NULL)
        eprintf("malloc of %u bytes failed:", n);
    return p;
}

/* erealloc: realloc and report if error */
void *erealloc(void *vp, size_t n)
{
    void *p;

    p = realloc(vp, n);
    if (p == NULL)
        eprintf("realloc of %u bytes failed:", n);
    return p;
}

/* estrdup: duplicate a string, report if error */
char *estrdup(char *s)
{
    char *t;

    t = (char *) malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    if (t == NULL)
        eprintf("estrdup(\"%.20s\") failed:", s);
    strcpy(t, s);
    return t;
}

/* progname: return stored name of program */
char *progname(void)
{
    return name;
}

/* setprogname: set stored name of program */
void setprogname(char *str)
{
    name = estrdup(str);
}
```

Comment: Maybe including the compiler output in your question would be a good idea.  I don't fancy reading six pages of code with only a vague idea of what error I'm looking for.

Comment: sorry about that. here is what i get: error line 71: 'line' : undeclared identifier, line 73: error C2065: 'element' : undeclared identifier

Comment: Can you try to isolate the troublesome piece of code and explain the intent of the code and the error it produces please. It will probably increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, your call to `fgets()` is strange: `line` should be a *pointer* to `char`, not a `char`. I don't know how that can compile.

Comment: sure, im having trouble in the main function where i declare the random_reader buffer. i want to read a file full of random numbers and store it in the array. it gives that the array and the integer 'element' are undeclared whereas i declare them clearly. do you want me to repost a shorter code?

Comment: That's one heck of a lot of code you got there...

Comment: so i change it to char* but i still get the same errors. i'm not sure why there are problems with declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *very* important that you read compiler error message from the top down.  You got 3 C2143 errors before you got the C2065 error.  It is typical that error messages get less accurate and informative, an earlier error may produce a slew of additional errors.  The first message complains about the *element* variable declaration.  Then you get additional errors for any line that contains *element* since the compiler couldn't properly parse the declaration.

Your compiler requires you to put all variable declarations *before* the code that uses them.

Also note that you've got two declarations for the *i* variable.  And that *line* needs to be an array of char: `char line[20];`  Moving the file reading code into a separate function would be a rather good idea.

Comment: `line` does not _have_ to be an array, otherwise a good answer. (It could be an actual pointer to some heap or stack buffer as well)

Comment: thanks Hans. I'll keep that in mind. Also, I'm trying to pass the array to the generate function and use its elements in the function. for some reason it just keeps giving me syntax error for the function prototype and definition. i'm reposting the updated code with comments as to where i made changes and am facing troubles. i tried to debug it but wasn't very successful. the errors are in lines 38, 81, 163

Comment: This is not okay, start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

In `main()` you have variable definitions appearing after code. This is permissible in C99 but not in C89, so if you're using an old C89 compiler, or something like MSVC which still doesn't support C99, then this is not going to compile. Move this block:

```
int element;
int random_num[10000];
char line; //each number
int i=0;
```

up above the code before it so that your variable definitions precede any actual code.